# Remove App Part chrome from JSOM (SP2013)

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, app-part

I've built a sharepoint hosted app that contains a single App Part. This part can be inserted in any page by adding a new App Part through the ribbon. This all works fine.

Now: The App part automatically adds the app part title (from Elements.xml) in the webpart-chrome, linking to the full-page application start-page.

I would like to remove the chrome (so title, and spacing) from the app part. Is it possible to do this from JSOM (html5 message like with resizing), or can I set this up from the Elements.xml file?

Note: This is not CSOM, only JSOM using the new app model. This means no server side coding, just a single app part that loads a page in an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

AppPart page can be edited using JavaScript or CSS.
AppPart title can be changed using [JSOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpart.title(v=office.15).aspx). Use [GetLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx).